# command handler not showing properly

Tags: discord, discord.js

i tried to add a command handler, but command files are showing incorrect values, for example the bot's ping is showing up as NaN and uptime/users/servers are all showing as zeros. the command was working fine until i moved it into it's own command file. i'm not sure what the problem is as no errors occur in the console. please help, the code to my index.js and one command file is below

my best guess as to where the issue is:
module.exports = {
    name: `bot`,
    description: `displays bot information.`,
    execute(message, args) {
//code
}

https://pastebin.com/hJ4nessW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `bot.js` file has some lines without using Discord.js's [Embed class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)...
At the first part where's

```js
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const bot = new Discord.Client(); // <- here
```

isn't necessary because it's defined in index.js, so should be use from index.js

```js
    switch (args[0]) {

        case `ping`:
            bot.commands.get(`ping`).execute(message, args, bot /* use it */ );
            break;

        case `bot`:
            bot.commands.get(`bot`).execute(message, args, bot /* use it */ );
            break;

    }
```

and bot.js

```js
 execute(message, args, bot) {
  // You can use bot variable
  // ...
```

I recommend to avoid [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), because it looks worse and spends a lot of time... I made the shorten, less lines and working code version ->  https://pastebin.com/sRNacWYt